# Non-X/Non-GUI terminal emulator for Ubuntu Server

Tags: command-line, server

I have a computer running Ubuntu Server (non-X/non-GUI), I need a terminal emulator which has VT100/VT320 capabilities like Gnome-Term and xTerm do on my other (GUI) Ubuntu box.

tMux and GNU Screen don't work properly (they don't respond to all VT commands like Gnome-Term and xTerm do).

So besides tMux and GNU Screen, are there any other non-X/non-GUI terminal emulators out there for Ubuntu?

Don't need modem or telnet capabilities, just a shell.

Comment: The built-in terminal (console) in Ubuntu Server (or regular Ubuntu via Ctrl-Alt-F6) is even worse; it doesn't have the VT line-drawing characters for making boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Kermit emulates all kinds of terminals. DEC VT52, VT100, VT102, VT220, VT320 terminals,  the Heath/Zenith-19 terminal and Tektronix graphics 4010/4014 terminals are all build in but others can be made on the run.

It runs on many clients. I run mine on a DOS 8086 (thats pre XT), a DOS 80286 and Windows10. It also runs on **ANY** linux, unix, DOS, atari, commodore, MSX, android, Apple  and windows machine. It might be a bit complicated in the beginning but all commands and ini files etc. are the same on all platforms so like with linux once learned used everywhere.
Kermit is free.